# alarm repeating at specific day not every day example ( Sunday, Tuesday , Friday)

Tags: android

I am tired to find specific day about alarm and always run every day pleas who can help me 
AND use these code what error about this ,run every so i send dayOfWeek=1; but run every day

```
 public void setAlarm(int dayOfWeek) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dayOfWeek+","+h+","+m, 22222).show();
     cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
     cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RemmemberActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, 0);
        pendingIntent    = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Long alarmTime = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
            am   = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After what I can see after a quick look you set alarm to repeat every 24 hours on this row:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);
```

Your `dayOfWeek` is only used for when it will go off the first time.

If you have an alarm that should go off three times a week on the same time, make three alarms that repeat once a week.

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);
```

Comment: ok but i have not constant three day (sun,tues,fri),may be different three day according checkbox chooses like a (mon ,wed ,sat)

Comment: Ok i used this line and fine run every Saturday am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent); but how can set  every Sunday

Comment: how the formula 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 works? if i wanted to alarm it every monday to friday?

Comment: @KairiSan As said then you need 5 alarms repeating once a week with different starting alarm times.

Comment: @sanna if i wanted to alarm it every 6pm? will it still work if i create 5 alarms?

Comment: can i use INTERVAL_DAY instead of 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ?

Comment: @KairiSan If you want it every dat you can use interval day. If you only want it weekdays, you need five alarms repeated interval week. 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 is a week, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 is a day.

Comment: i use this 
`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c1.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c2.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c3.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);`

Answer (score 0):

finally this right solution if set as (sun,tus ,fri) you must create three alarm for these three day 
the following code set alarm every sunday and send dayOfWeek=1;
important note every create a run at some day must change request code in every intnet (12345)
in example

```
 public void setAlarm_sun(int dayOfWeek) {
     cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sun "+cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), 222).show();

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finsh", 222).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         Long alarmTime = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

       // am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,7* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,7* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);

}
```